# How do I add a front menu button that redirects to another website or sub-domain?

Tags: html, pages

*Hello there,*

> I would like to add a front menu
>   button (viz. Home, About, Archive
>   etc.) to my blog that links to another
>   website. WordPress only shows the
>   pages that I have created using
>   dashboard in the front menu.

I hope my question is clear. Let's assume I have a Yoga blog and a Yoga store at another website. I'd like to add a "STORE" button -- after my Home, About and other pages -- that links outside the WP blog.

Thanks for your help. :)

PS - I am using [lightword](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/lightword) theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lightword theme as wp_nav_menu enabled so you can create your menu from the

> Appearance → Menus panel

where you have Custom Links and that is just what you are looking for.
you can read more on how to use [WordPress Menus panel](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I had the "Use basic wordpress pages/categories in front menu" options checked in the theme settings. So I was not able to see that custom menu that I created anywhere. Took me hours to figure that out. It was helpful.  :)

Comment: Glad i could help